# Cannot select only columns with same column name from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables named `a`, and `b`.

Table `a` contains 50 columns, and table `b` contain 75 columns

There are same column name in this two tables. How to find the same columns?

Comment: What is `the same column SQL server` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can query the `sys.columns` and then do an `INTERSECT` to find the common column names:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'a'

INTERSECT 

SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'b'
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Felix Pamittan

Comment: Glad to have been of help! [Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Please try this it will  help you

```
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='a'
INTERSECT
select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='b'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also query for the view

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

This way:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name IN ('your_a_table','your_b_table')
ORDER BY column_name
```

With this you can get a nice view of all the columns in common (and other ones too) between the two tables.